# C - double result returning the value of 0

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    double result = a / b;
    printf("%d divided by %d makes %f\n", a, b, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Expecting that the `%f` would return 0.500000, I ran the code and it turned out to be 0.000000.

Is there a reason that the `result` variable is returning a zero value?

Comment: shouldn't it be %lf for a double?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's performing integer devision since `a` and `b` are `int`s, try this

```
double result = (float) a / (float) b;
```

Comment: To be more specific, the compiler doesn't care what type you're assigning the expression to.  The precision of an operation is dependent only on the operand types.  In this case, `int / int` uses integer division.  By casting one (or both) of the arguments to `float`, the operation is promoted to floating-point division.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to wait a few more minutes to accept your answer now.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? If I run the the same code in Java, say, `double result = (float) a / (float) b;` and run `System.out.println(result);`, now it's returning a very strange value, something like `0.6000000238418579`. Can you also explain why?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer No, sorry I don't know java.

Comment: Alright.. better check out the other questions. Thanks for the answer anyways! I accepted it now :)

Answer (score 3):

You are dividing two integers, which will provide an integer result. In C, this means it will simply discard the fractional portion, leaving the 0.

You can cast one or both of the operands (a or b) as follows and it should clear up:

```
double result = (float) a / b;
```